# SAS date and time to Normal date and time format (Y-M-D H:m:S)

Tags: r, date, time, sas, as.date

I have obtained data from a remote tagging experiment and the dates are in SAS format (43255.940972). The last level of information I want to extract are seconds. I was trying this:

```
as.Date(data$Date, origin = "1960-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

But all I get in return is Year-Month-Day but no time details. How do I specify, using this command that I also want that information to be returned?

Thanks

Comment: what is the result of the above time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by @Onyambu

```
as.POSIXct(a*86400,origin="1899-12-30")
```

Some documentation you can read on those [functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) and [date time](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html) in general.

Comment: 43255 itself is the year 2018. Your code is miles away

Comment: isn't that assuming the origin is `1900-01-01`?

Comment: With EXCEL and SAS, the date numeric conversion takes place taking origin to be 1899-12-30 for windows OS and 1904-01-01 for MAC OS. check [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/) for example

Comment: for this you should do something like `as.POSIXct(a*86400,origin="1899-12-30")` if you are on windows

Comment: so my original answer is obviously wrong, I had thought SAS used 1960-01-01 as their origin for all date formats represented integers, see [this](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm)

Comment: my bad. I thought SAS and excel had the same origin. Usually 43 thousand sounds as EXCEL. Although if we are using the site you shared, 43 thousand itself as an integer will go way deep into the future. I guess there is a way to transform this.

Comment: as.POSIXct(a*86400,origin="1899-12-30"), solved the issue, the main problem is that I was taking an incorrect origin and I was not considering the conversion. Thank you

Comment: you should probably give @Onyambu the answer for this, I was completely off